# How can I mask uiimages either over or under another uiimage with transparency?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, mask

I'm trying to take something like an image of a triangle where the background is transparent and apply a polka dot image to it on either the triangle portion or the background portion based on the users preference. For instance, how could I apply polka dots to the triangle portion and then stripes to the transparent portion of the image. Is there a masking technique for such a thing?

Many thanks,

Comment: can you please share the output image?

Answer (score 0):

```
func maskImage(image:UIImage, mask:(UIImage))->UIImage{

 let imageReference = image.CGImage
 let maskReference = mask.CGImage

 let imageMask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskReference),
 CGImageGetHeight(maskReference),
 CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskReference),
 CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskReference),
 CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskReference),
 CGImageGetDataProvider(maskReference), nil, true)

 let maskedReference = CGImageCreateWithMask(imageReference, imageMask)

 let maskedImage = UIImage(CGImage:maskedReference!)

 return maskedImage}
```

usage

`let image = UIImage(named: "image2.png")
let maskingImage = UIImage(named: "mask6.png")
imageView.image = maskImage(image!, mask: maskingImage!)`